# Hide "sent by" information in Outlook

Tags: php, api, email, outlook, mailgun

Is it possible to hide "sent by" information about mailgun in Outlook email client?
That's how it's look like [image]

Email has been sent by mailgun API from the server.

Comment: If you are sending emails over mailgun's server then you can only ask them to remove it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as On Behalf Of notation. The way to eliminate this notation is to ensure that the email address for the Sender: field and the From: field use the same domain. For instance, for both the Sender and From field, they both need to end in either domain.com or mg.domain.com, whichever one is currently a custom domain on your Mailgun CP.

When sending, you should always make sure the domain you are inputting in the From: field matches the domain you have added and are sending from using Mailgun. If these domains do not match your messages have a high chance of getting marked as spam and showing up with "on behalf of" or "via".